# for each loop filter -like email address

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to apply a filter -like using a for each loop based on the domain of email address.

I've tried other examples found on the web but it yields no results on my end

This is what im currently using:

```
$somedata = Import-csv -Path \pathto\data.csv 

Foreach ($domain in $somedata) {
Get-aduser -Filter { emailaddress -Like "*$domain.email_domain"} -Properties emailaddress
}
```

example: $domain.email_domain would be 'gmail.com' and im looking for all users with 'gmail.com' at the end of their email

I expected this to run but nothing happens. If I do a one-off as such it will work:

```
Get-aduser -Filter { emailaddress -Like "*gmail.com"} -Properties emailaddress
```

Comment: Change $domain.email_domain to $($domain.email_domain). Variable expansion will stop at the dot within a string. The subexpression operator allows the variable property to be evaluated

Comment: Thanks! By adding the “*” in the beginning I was able to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter text should be `"*$($domain.email_domain)"`

```
$somedata = Import-csv -Path \pathto\data.csv 

Foreach ($domain in $somedata) {
Get-aduser -Filter { emailaddress -Like "*$($domain.email_domain)"} -Properties emailaddress
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had to create a separate variable and add that after the like statement - where $somevariable = “*$($domain.email_address)”